# Определение цвета элемента в canvas при клике

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Возникла проблема с получением нужного цвета. В canvas нарисовала две фигуры. Необходимо при нажатии клавиши мыши получить цвет фигуры или фона, в зависимости от того на что нажали. Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: с примером кода проще работать, поэтому, если возможно, добавьте хотя бы html

Answer (score 1):

### canvas - определение цвета пикселя по клику

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const w = canvas.width = 200
const h = canvas.height = 200
canvas.style.border = 'solid 1px'
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 10, 20, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
ctx.fillRect(20, 10, 20, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,255)";
ctx.fillRect(40, 10, 20, 20);
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const img_data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);//ImageData
  const pix = img_data.data;
  // console.dir(pix)
  const red = pix[0];
  const green = pix[1];
  const blue = pix[2];
  const alpha = pix[3];
  console.log(`красный ${red} зелёный ${green} голубой ${blue} прозрачность ${alpha}`);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${pix.join(',')})`
}
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ImageData